# How to check all item in your list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary like this:

```
roles = [
    {
        "name": "project_management",
        "id": "25"
    },
    {
        "name": "pm.project",
        "id": "26"
    }
]
```

I want to check each item in another list which contain `id` in primary list. 
that another list may like this:

```
l = ['25', '80']
```

I wrote a function to find an `id` in list:

```
def has_id(_id):
    return bool(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == _id, roles))
```

now, how i can write one statement to return me `True` or `False` for other list in primary list.

***I don't want use `for` statement.***

Comment: For the sample data  you have given, you want `False` as output, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye, exactly

Comment: `I don't want use for statement.` - Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @thefourtheye because one statement is very beautiful

Comment: Your `has_id` is broken. E.g. `has_id(42)` is `True`.

Comment: @poke! i tested, its ok and return False

Comment: Only in Python 2 though, and only because of the behavior of `filter`. You should do something like `any(x['id'] == _id for x in roles)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with thanks of all

```
def check(_list):
    return all(map(has_id, list))

print check(l)

False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` function to check if every role's `id` is in `l` or not and then combine that will `all` function, like this

```
>>> l = ['25', '80']
>>> all(map(lambda x: x["id"] in l, roles))
False
>>> l = ['25', '26']
>>> all(map(lambda x: x["id"] in l, roles))
True
```

**Note:** Here we check if the id is in `l` with `in` operator. In a list, it will do linear checking. If you can convert your `l` to a set, it will be very fast as sets use hashes to find the items.

---

Better solution here would be using an generator expression. In Python 2.x, `map` actually generates a list, but we may not need to create an entire list, because we can return `False`, if at least one of the ids don't exist in `l`. `all` will iterate the generator expression, get the values one by one and it will return `False` immediately if the current element is not Truthy otherwise it will check the next element.

(**Note:** I know it has `for` in it, but it will not executed completely. It will just be executed on-demand).

```
>>> l = ['25', '80']
>>> all(role["id"] in l for role in roles)
False
>>> l = ['25', '26']
>>> all(role["id"] in l for role in roles)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for all elements within `l` you can use `set.intersection` like following :

```
>>> l = ['25', '80']
from operator import itemgetter
>>> bool(set(map(itemgetter('id'),roles)).intersection(l)==set(l))
False
>>> l = ['25', '26']
>>> bool(set(map(itemgetter('id'),roles)).intersection(l)==set(l))
True
```

*Note* that this answer doesn't used loop and i think its the closest to what you want.Also you can use other built-in functions like `all` and `any` but they used python `for` loop in the source!

This is the [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function :

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `map(itemgetter('id'))` instead of the lambda?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Yep, i just was thinking about that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools) function method like :

```
>>> l = ["25", "80"]
>>> print map(has_id, l)
>>> [True, False]
```

`map(function, sequence)` calls function(item) for each of the sequence’s items and returns a list of the return values.